# Override JSON view in RequestHandler in CakePHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp, requesthandler

I want to rewrite JSON View in the RequestHandler. So there's a file `project_root/lib/JsonView.php`. What I want to do is to

- Import the `JsonView.php` file in another file in `project_root/app/View/CustomJsonView.php`. (I think I could use `App:import`, would it be right ?)
- Choose this file as the custom in requestHandler like this:

`public $components = array('RequestHandler' => array( 'viewClassMap' => array('json' => '/right/way/to/this/file/CustomJsonView', )));`

But how do I write the right way for this file ?
I also saw this one https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent::viewClassMap
but there is no explanation about the right paths to the file. My CakePHP version is 2.4.4 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to pass full paths, but "short classnames", just like shown in the linked example, where `ApiKit.MyJson` refers to the `MyJsonView` view class in the `ApiKit` plugin, which could be located in `app/Plugin/ApiKit/View/MyJsonView.php`.

If you follow the conventions and place your `CustomJsonView` class in `app/View/CustomJsonView.php` [**as shown in the docs**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#creating-your-own-view-classes), you then just pass `CustomJson` as the short classname in the request handlers `viewClassMap` option.

Whether you use `App::import()` or just `require` to include the `/lib/JsonView.php` file, is up to you, both works. In any way you must make sure that whatever you are importing there doesn't clash with existing class names (`JsonView` is a kinda reserved name as it already exists in the core), and that it is either following the CakePHP view class naming conventions, or you must extend it.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Creating your own view classes](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#creating-your-own-view-classes)**
- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > General Purpose > App Class> Loading Vendor Files](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files)**

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I just included the the file this way `App::uses('JsonView', 'View');` and then just extended it. In the RequestHandler I was able to call it just by name, the custom file was in `app/View/` folder.